# Platform-specific dependency with CocoaPods

Tags: cocoapods, podspec

I'm [creating a Podspec](https://github.com/niklassaers/Bolt-swift/blob/master/BoltProtocol.podspec) and for the macOS target, I'd like to add a [dependency](https://github.com/niklassaers/ShellOut/blob/master/ShellOut.podspec). Is there a way I in the Podspec can define a dependency that is only to be included for the macOS platform, and not include it for iOS? (the dependency is not available for iOS, and I've #if'ed around that in my code)

Comment: `s.osx.depedency = MyOnlyOSXDependecy`?